# Как добавить страничку в мои на сайте без регистрации

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, cookie

Подскажите как осуществить такую задачу. Человек просматривает страницу, она ему понравилась, жмет на кнопку добавить в поравившиеся и позже смотрит, но без регистрации, я так понимаю там куки используются, ну ява скрипт это понятно. Вот пример на этом сайте http://vseigru.net/igry-klikery/28775-igra-kliker-pechenki-spasenie-mira.html
Вобщем буду рад если покажите на самом простеньком примере. Спасибо.

Comment: Создаёте куку с уникальным ID (например хэш времени с IP посетителя). Помещаете в БД информацию с этим ID и списком сохранённых страниц.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Ну примерно я так представлял себе.